# redis setstring System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, caching, redis

I want to set cache to redis but I get an reror:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code

```
DistributedCacheEntryOptions options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions();
options.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
options.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
options.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

_distributedCache.SetString("zaman", DateTime.Now.ToString(), options);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ8hG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e8Yw.png)

Even though I filled in all the relevant fields, the code throws a `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: On second link open the Call Stack